# Building user authentication in ruby on rails, got undefined method `dashboard_users_index_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I watched the railscast for building your own user authentication. I'm getting this undefined method error. Where should this method be defined, the controller, model, or neither?

```
Showing /opt/csdashboard/app/views/dashboard_users/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `dashboard_users_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8480988fa8>:0x007f84809880f8>
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <h1>Sing Up</h1>
2: 
3: <%= form_for @dashboard_user do |f|%>
4:     <% if @dashboard_user.errors.any? %>
5:      <div class="alert-error">
6:        <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
```

Here is my `dashboard_user/new.html.erb` file

```
<h1>Sing Up</h1>

<%= form_for @dashboard_user do |f|%>
    <% if @dashboard_user.errors.any? %>
     <div class="alert-error">
       <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
       <ul>
         <% for message in @dashboard_user.full_message %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
         <% end %>
       </ul>
     </div>
    <% end %>

        <p>
          <%= f.label :email %><br />
          <%= f.text_field :email %>
        </p>

        <p>
          <%= f.label :password %><br />
          <%= f.password_filed :password %>
        </p>

         <p>
           <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
           <%= f.password_filed :password_confirmation %>
         </p>
    <p class='ui-button'><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Here is the model:

```
class DashboardUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_hash, :password_salt
  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    dashboard_user = find_by_email(email)
    if dashboard_user && dashboard_user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, dashboard_user.password_salt)
      dashboard_user
    else
      nil?
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash =BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end

end
```

Here is the controller:

```
class DashboardUsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUsers.new
  end

  def create
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUsers.new(params[:user])
    if @dashboard_user.save
      redirect_to index, :notice => 'Signed up!'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Update with routes.rb
Speaking of routes, what should I do with `get '/' => 'csdashboard#index'`. This was the first route before I added user auth.

```
Csdashboard::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :dashboard_users
  resources :sessions
  resources :csdashboard
  get '/log_out' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'log_out'
  get '/log_in' => 'sessions#new', :as => 'log_in'
  get '/sign_up' => 'dashboard_users#new', :as => 'sign_up'
  root :to => 'dashboard_users#new'
  get '/' => 'csdashboard#index'
  get '/img/:name.:ext', :to => redirect('/assets/%{name}.%{ext}')
  match '/404' => 'errors#not_found'
  match '/422' => 'errors#server_error'
  match '/500' => 'errors#server_error'
end
```

Comment: Do `rake routes` and check for a route with prefix `dashboard_users_index`. If it is missing then you need to create it and map it to an action in your controller.

Comment: What Ruby on Rails version do you have?

Comment: Rails 4.0.2, Ruby 2.0.0p247.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the route with name `dashboard_users_index` and method `post` to be defined in `routes.rb`.

Can you show us your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: Added routes in original post.

Comment: Added `post '/dashboard_users_index' => 'dashboard_users#new'` it's working better now. I did use post and get, same results. What would I need to use post for vs get in this instance? Thanks for your help. Never mind, post works when adding the user.

Comment: Usually, forms are using POST or PUT/PATCH method, because it hides the request params from the url, has no limitation on the length of the request, etc.